# Are item keys required when rendering an array in React v15?

Tags: reactjs

In earlier versions of React, I remember getting a warning when rendering an array without specifying a unique `key` for every item:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.items.map(item => <span>{item.text}</span>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I understand that it is recommended to specify keys when rendering a dynamic list of items (where items can be added or removed) to help the reconciliation algorithm. I'd like to understand:

1. Why React doesn't warn anymore when keys are missing?
2. For static lists, is there a value in specifying item keys?

Official pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: The corresponding code is still there: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src%2Fisomorphic%2Fclassic%2Felement%2FReactElementValidator.js#L71

Comment: And the error is still there https://jsfiddle.net/t0n6393r/

Comment: The error is still there. If you're not seeing this warning maybe you're running in production?

Comment: Is it possible that OP is compiling his code for production, which eliminates debugging code?

Comment: @JohnnyMagrippis, yup. Quite sure that's the case here. During upgrade from 0.14 > 15 he might also have turned on production, perhaps by accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I still see [`this warning message`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src%2Fisomorphic%2Fclassic%2Felement%2FReactElementValidator.js#L71), and in [`official release notes`](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/04/07/react-v15.html) there is no mention about this case

[`Example`](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/04/07/react-v15.html)

Comment: Hmmm.. Looks like something weird is going on in my codebase. The browser doesn't show the warning, but I can still see the warning in the terminal while server rendering.